# How to fix Dompdf error ( min/max width is undefined for table row)?

Tags: php, html, dompdf, invoice

I'm getting this error :
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Dompdf\Exception' with message 'Min/max width is undefined for table rows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Invoice 01</title>
</head>
<body style="padding:40px ;font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">
  <page>
    <div style="display:flex;align-items:center; justify-content: space-between;margin-bottom: 30px;">
      <div style=" display:flex; align-items: center;">
        <img src="images/Alfnr.png" alt="" style="
          width: 180px;
          aspect-ratio: 3/2;
          object-fit: contain;">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
          <h1 style="color: #f1d649;text-transform:uppercase;padding: 0;margin: 0;">Company name</h1>
          <span>Company tagline</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: #f1d649;font-size:35px;padding: 5px 40px;box-shadow: -3px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.38);">
        Invoice
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="line-height: 1.4;">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom:5px;">Invoive to :</h2>
      <h3>MR. LOREM IPSUM</h3>
      <p>01 Lorem Street Dummy, <br>
        Location, Lorem Area Park <br>
        1234abc67x
      </p>
    </div>
    <div style="width: fit-content;margin-left: auto;">
      <table style="border:none; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
          <td style="width:64px;font-weight: bold;">Invoice#</td>
          <td style="width: 64px;padding:5px 20px;">123456</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-weight: bold;">Date</td>
          <td style="padding:5px 20px;">01 / 02 / 2021</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <table style="width:100%;border-collapse: collapse;;margin:10px 0; background-color: #fafaf8;">
      <tr style="background-color:#f1d649;border-bottom: 2px solid #ababa9;">
        <th style="width:57px;padding:15px 1px;">SL,</th>
        <th style="width:560px;text-align:start;padding-left:  40px;">Item Description</th>
        <th style="width:57px;">Qty</th>
        <th style="width:142px;">Price</th>
        <th style="width: 142px;">Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ababa9;text-align: center;">
        <td style="padding:15px 1px; background-color: #edefec;">1</td>
        <td style="text-align:start;padding-left:40px;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">1</td>
        <td>$25.00</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">$25.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ababa9;text-align: center;">
        <td style="padding:15px 1px; background-color: #edefec;">2</td>
        <td style="text-align:start;padding-left:40px;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">2</td>
        <td>$25.00</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">$50.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ababa9;text-align: center;">
        <td style="padding:15px 1px; background-color: #edefec;">3</td>
        <td style="text-align:start;padding-left:40px;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">3</td>
        <td>$25.00</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">$75.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ababa9;text-align: center;">
        <td style="padding:15px 1px; background-color: #edefec;">4</td>
        <td style="text-align:start;padding-left:40px;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">4</td>
        <td>$25.00</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">$50.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid #ababa9;text-align: center;">
        <td style="padding:15px 1px; background-color: #edefec;">5</td>
        <td style="text-align:start;padding-left:40px;">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">5</td>
        <td>$25.00</td>
        <td style=" background-color: #edefec;">$25.00</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Thank you for business with us!</p>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content:space-between;
    margin: 30px 0;">
      <table style="width:295px;background-color: #f1d649; padding: 15px;box-shadow: 4px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.38);">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3" style="width: 272px;;text-align:start;font-size: 1.3rem;">Payment Info :</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Account#</td>
          <td style="padding:0 10px ;">:</td>
          <td>1234 5678 91011</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A/C Name</td>
          <td style="padding:0 10px ;">:</td>
          <td>Mr Lorem Ipsum Dolor</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Bank Details</td>
          <td style="padding:0 10px ;">:</td>
          <td>Your Bank Details</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table style="border-collapse: collapse;width: 200px;">
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:5px 15px;">Sub Total</td>
          <td style="padding:0 0px ;">:</td>
          <td>$225.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
          <td style="padding:5px 15px;">Tax</td>
          <td style="padding:0 0px ;">:</td>
          <td>0.00%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color: #f1d649; padding: 15px;box-shadow: 4px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.38);">
          <td style="padding:5px 15px;">Total</td>
          <td style="padding:0 10px ;"></td>
          <td style="padding-right: 15px;">$225.00</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content:space-between;">
      <div class="terms">
        <h3>Terms & Conditions :</h3>
        <p style="max-width: 400px;">consecteture minus Autem itaque quibusdam voluptatum minus quasi repudiandae? Earum consequuntur libero sed dolorem facilis exercitationem unde. Qui, libero expedita.</p>
      </div>
      <div style="align-self:flex-end;text-align: center;">
        <div style="width:200px;height:60px;border-bottom: 2px solid #ababa9;"></div>
        <p style="margin-top:5px;">Singature</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </page>
</body>
</html>
```

ignore this :
Le lorem ipsum est, en imprimerie, une suite de mots sans signification utilisée à titre provisoire pour calibrer une mise en page, le texte définitif venant remplacer le faux-texte dès qu'il est prêt ou que la mise en page est achevée. Généralement, on utilise un texte en faux latin, le Lorem ipsum ou Lipsum.

When my client try to generate pdf from this HTML invoice he got that error.
Where is the probleme in my code ?

> Blockquote
> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

remove this line `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`
Doompdf seek this font in local server, this is the problem..!!